# AI Asset Generation for Unity

Tags: image-generation, games

I struggle to get good 3D game assets as a coder and amateur Unity game dev. I don't want to buy expensive assets for a game with no commercial potential, but free 3D game assets are limited in scope and quality.

Recently, a designer friend told me that some AI image gen programs can generate 3D assets. I wonder whether anyone has successfully used GenAI image tools specifically for Unity asset creation. Any tips?

Comment: I've tried some text-to-3D libs for Unity but they're all too early to be useful yet, with model clarity severely lacking. However, keep a close eye on Midjourney, who are working on this, as I expect are others. In the meantime, note there's many cool Public Domain or Creative Commons 3D libraries you can use, like https://poly.pizza

Comment: I wrote this which can help you to get texture bump map from a single image: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1asSX-OD--bhHRTqPs5cLHsLtpKmooUaa?usp=sharing. It cannot generate complete 3D assets tho, bas relief is the best it can achieve at the moment.